# How to write forEach method without repeating my code? ShowWeather function javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach

```
function showForecastWeather(data) {
    forecastTitle.forEach((title) => {
        
        if (title.dataset.src === '1') {
            const d = new Date(data.list[7].dt * 1000);
            const dayName = days[d.getDay()];
            title.innerText = dayName.slice(0,3);
        };
        if (title.dataset.src === '2') {
            const d = new Date(data.list[15].dt * 1000);
            const dayName = days[d.getDay()];
            title.innerText = dayName.slice(0, 3)
        };
        if (title.dataset.src === '3') {
            const d = new Date(data.list[23].dt * 1000);
            const dayName = days[d.getDay()];
            title.innerText = dayName.slice(0, 3)
        };
        if (title.dataset.src === '4') {
            const d = new Date(data.list[31].dt * 1000);
            const dayName = days[d.getDay()];
            title.innerText = dayName.slice(0, 3)
        };
        if (title.dataset.src === '5') {
            const d = new Date(data.list[39].dt * 1000);
            const dayName = days[d.getDay()];
            title.innerText = dayName.slice(0, 3)
        };

    });
```

How can I write this without repeating my code so much? Like as a function or something?
Is it possible to use index parameter in forEach() method to display API data?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that changes between the conditions is the index you use to access the `list` array. As such you can genericise your logic by calculating this value from the `src`. Something like this:

```js
function showForecastWeather(data) {
  forecastTitle.forEach(title => {
    const index = (parseInt(this.dataset.src, 10) * 8) - 1;
    const d = new Date(data.list[index].dt * 1000);
    const dayName = days[d.getDay()];
    title.innerText = dayName.slice(0, 3);
  });
}
```

Comment: This looks like good solution. what does the ``` const index =(parseInt(this.dataset.src, 10) * 8) - 1; ``` actually do?

Comment: `parseInt()` takes the string `src` value and turns it in to an integer. From there it's a mathematical operation to turn it in to the relevant index, eg. `1` becomes `7`, `2` becomes `15` and so on